# Spring : How to Validate Beans inside ArrayList

Tags: json, hibernate, spring-mvc, jackson, bean-validation

I have the following mapping handler:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/product")
public class ProductController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, ?> update(@Valid @RequestBody ListOfProduct productList) {

        if (productDao.saveOrUpdateAll(productList)) {
                return jsonUtils.statusMessage(true, "Updated successfully.");
            }

        return jsonUtils.statusMessage(false, "Failed.");
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String handleMethodArgumentNotValidException(MethodArgumentNotValidException error) {
        return "Bad request: " + error.getMessage();
    }

    public static class ListOfProduct extends ArrayList<Product> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public ListOfProduct() {
            super();
        }
    }
}

@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Min(1)
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5)
    private String name;

    public product() {
    }

        // getters and setters
}
```

I'm trying to validate this JSON:

```
[{"id":6, "name":""}]
```

It is supposed to be a violation for constraint @Size of "name" property.

And it is supposed to be handled by **handleMethodArgumentNotValidException()** inside the controller.

But instead, I got this exception:

```
Jan 21, 2012 10:25:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/WebTest] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.tes.web.entity.Product] during update time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='size must be between 5 and 2147483647', propertyPath=name, rootBeanClass=class com.tes.web.entity.Product, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}'}
]] with root cause
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.tes.web.entity.Product] during update time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='size must be between 5 and 2147483647', propertyPath=name, rootBeanClass=class com.tes.web.entity.Product, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}'}
]
```

Any suggestion how to solve this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The exception in your log is a `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException`, but your exception handler is for the exception type `MethodArgumentNotValidException`. I think you should try to declare your handler for `ConstraintViolationException`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But it's supposed to throw `MethodArgumentNotValidException`. If `ConstraintViolationException` is thrown instead of `MethodArgumentNotValidException`, it means that `@Valid` annotation in `update()` method is useless (validation is not done via spring).

Comment: Unless you aren't invoking validation by other means I'd think validation actually is triggered by Spring (note that Spring MVC performed a validation triggered by `@Valid` also in 3.0.x, while `MethodArgumentNotValidException` was just introduced with Spring 3.1). I can't tell thoughm which configuration/set-up causes which exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

@Valid on an @RequestBody should indeed result in a MethodArgumentNotValidException. Try putting a break in RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor line 74. If you believe there is an issue report it in JIRA.